# Would Prometheus and Grafana be an incorrect tool to use for request logging, tracking and analysis?

Tags: node.js, prometheus, grafana

I currently am creating a faster test harness for our team and will be recording a baseline from our prod sdk run and our staging sdk run. I am running the tests via jest and want to eventually fire the parsed requests and their query params to a datastore of sorts and have a nice UI around it for tracking.

I thought that Prometheus and Grafana would be able to provide that, but after getting a little POC for myself working yesterday it seems that this combo is more used for tracking application performance rather than request log handling/manipulation/tracking.

Is this the right tool to be using for what I am trying to achieve and if so might someone shed some light on where I might find some more reading aligned with what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus does only one thing and  it well. It collects metrics and store them. It is used for monitoring your infrastructure or applications to monitor performance, availability, error rates etc. You can write rules using PromQL expression to create alert based on conditions and send them to alert manager which can send it to Pager duty, slack, email or any ticketing system. Even though Prometheus comes with a UI for visualising the data it's better to use Grafana since it's pretty good with it and easy to analyse data.

If you are looking tools for distributed tracing you can check Jaeger

Comment: Thanks @slashpai for the info!